# Eiffel: change the signature of a inherited feature

Tags: eiffel

How is the correct way to change the signature of a feature in Eiffel if any? if there is no option as I understood, how would be the correct way to define in a parent class that there will be a feature to be able to select but still don't know arguments number and types (types are resolvable with polymorphism...)

Is the only available playing with polymorphism having an argument into class a to select of type ANY?

### class SELECTABLE

```
class SELECTABLE

    select
        deferred 
        end

end -- class
```

### class DB_SERVICE

```
class DB_SERVICE

inherit
    SELECTABLE
        (...)

feature -- Status setting


    select (a_db_connection: DB_CONNECTION)
        local
            l_qry: STRING
        do
            item := first_item_from_qry (l_qry)
        end

end -- class
```

Comment: Maybe explain the use case for `SELECTABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Having the following in class `SELECTABLE` is indeed a solution:

```
select (a: ANY)
    deferred
    end
```

Another solution is to use `TUPLE`:

```
select (a: TUPLE)
    deferred
    end
```

This allows you to have more than one argument in descendant classes:

```
select (a: TUPLE [db_connection: DB_CONNECTION])
    do
        a.db_connection.do_something
    end
```

which can be called:

```
a_db_server.select (a_db_connection)
```

or:

```
select (a: TUPLE [db_connection: DB_CONNECTION; db_parameters: DB_PARAMETERS])
    do
        a.db_connection.do_something (a.db_parameters)
    end
```

which can be called:

```
a_db_server.select (a_db_connection, a_dp_parameters)
```

Note that in that case, the need for the explicit tuple notation `[...]` in the argument of `select` is optional.

And of course, `select` is a keyword in Eiffel. You will have to use another name for your feature.

Comment: what powerful the tupple!!!! didnt think about it!!! thx a lot! and could we play with detachable for optional parameters???

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work. You would have to pass an explicit Void.